# How to add a custom text filter, redirect to an external site?

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

My `redmine` version is 2.5.2 .
Our team use `redmine` to manage the project progress, but our company uses `mantis` as bug tracker. So, I hope to filter the text `mantis:113` to a link which links to the bug page with id `113` on the mantis site.

Is there any plugin which supports this function ? Or, how to configure it on the `redmine` ?

For example, an issue or a comment has following text,

```
mantis:113 is fixed.
```

The `mantis:113` will be auto processed to a link to the bug page with id 113.